# Can the C# method interface be redesign to get rid of `new string[] {}` to improve readability?

Tags: c#, refactoring

Having a method as follows, I would like to simplify passing the arguments when using it:

```
public virtual Segment AddDataElement(string[] dataElement)
{
    dataElementList.Add(dataElement);
    return this;
}
```

The method is called many times like this:

```
message.AddSegment("NAD")
    .AddDataElement(new string[] { partyFunctionCodeQualifier })
    .AddDataElement(new string[] { partyIdentifier, "", "92" });
```

Is it possible to modify the method definition so that it would be possible to write **more readable** call lile this?

```
message.AddSegment("NAD")
    .AddDataElement(partyFunctionCodeQualifier)
    .AddDataElement(partyIdentifier, "", "92");
```

Can the later be internally transformed to the earlier form?

Comment: As a completely side note, I'd strongly advise you to start following .NET naming conventions to make your code more idiomatic: `dataElement` instead of `data_element`, `partyFunctionCodeQualifier` instead of `party_function_code_qualifier` etc.

Comment: @DaisyShipton: There is a reason for that form of identifiers. They are actually taken directly from the implementation guideline document. I have only changed the first letter to lowercase and replaced space by underscore. I have found that form more readable than the .NET convention, and I can see no reason to change it. While I understand the reason for the conventions, sometimes the convention is euphemism for "dogma". ;)

Comment: Well, I heartily disagree. That will end up being distracting to every C# developer who's used to the convention from other places - and either you'll be consistent in every codebase that is worked on with this one, or you'll end up with a mess of different styles. I've worked in codebases which use a mixture of naming conventions, and it's horrible. I prefer to work with a convention I dislike (e.g. putting `_` at the start of field names, which is at least a private implementation detail) than to work in an inconsistent codebase. Your call of course, but it's *not* just dogma.

Comment: (I'd also make the point that when writing a question or answer on Stack Overflow, if you're aware of a commonly-used convention that you happen not to use yourself, it's particularly important to follow the convention. Anything that acts as a distraction between you and your reader is a bad thing. While you can agree to use a different convention within your team, at which point it won't be a distraction, you can't do the same thing on Stack Overflow.)

Comment: @DaisyShipton: OK. I will revise my desicision. ;)

Comment: @DaisyShipton: I may have been wrong. I have changed the identifiers to follow the convention, and the source is reasonably readable. Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely do this.

Firstly, you can use implicit array typing to reduce `new string[]` to `new[]`:

```
.AddDataElement(new[] { partyFunctionCodeQualifier })
```

Secondly, you can change the parameter to be a *parameter array* with the `params` keyword:

```
public virtual Segment AddDataElement(params string[] dataElement)
```

At that point, you can indeed specify just a single string - or multiple strings without building an array in source code. The compiler will create the array for you.

Comment: This is nice. Thanks, Daisy, for the answer. Have a nice day.

Comment: For your information, I have changed the identifiers in the question.

Comment: @pepr: Great, thanks. I've changed the identifiers in my answer too.